# Как устроена логика программы

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток. Разбираю задачку.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
float fact(float q){
    return !q ? 1: q*fact(q-1);}
float funct(float n, float m){
    return (fact(n)*fact(m))/fact(n+m);
}
int main ( ){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    float n,m;
    cout<<"Введите n"<<endl;
    cin>>n;

    cout<<"Введите m"<<endl;
    cin>>m;
    cout<<"Результат"<<funct(n,m);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос по работе программы. Вызывается функция с плавающей точкой, дальше идет рекурсия, но для чего она?

Далее идет описание искомой функции. Вот до int main не совсем понятно что происходит.
Дальше ясно: ввожу n и m, вызываю функцию funct, передаю в неё n и m.

Comment: Слово "факториал" вам не о чём не говорит?

Comment: Математически я понимаю что представляет из себя факториал..но в данном контексте не очень ясно

Comment: Вообще это кажется обратным числом к перестановкам с повторениями элементов двух типов. А дальше -- читайте комбинаторику, я тут мало чем могу помочь

Comment: @amora, или Вам непонятно как работает функция `fact()`?

Comment: Да, именно)

Comment: @amora, всем известно, что факториал числа n (n>0) - это

    n! = 1*2*3*...*n = n * (n-1)!

Посмотрите на функцию, сделайте выводы

Comment: @amora, вообще говоря, реализация факториала очень хромает. Что будет при отрицательных значениях q? Или для не целых? Например, 0.000001 - почти ноль, но проблема очевидна.

Comment: Вообще-то обычно, говоря о факториале, имеется в виду факториал *целого натурального числа*.  При этом (совершенно естественно для англоязычной математики) 0! считается равным 1.

Поэтому функция `func(float)` из вопроса выглядит странно. 

--

Я немного покопался в гугле и нашел, что существует и [Факториал вещественного](http://plus7.ucoz.ru/blog/faktorial_necelogo_chisla/2011-12-05-3) числа, который считается по формуле:

    X! = N! * ((N+1) ** d)
    N  - целая часть числа X
    d – мантисса числа X

@amora, в принципе, что *нужно для Вашей задачи?*

Comment: С func(float) разобралась, переделала немного..Моя задача, более или менее решена "описать функцию F(m,n)=n!*m!/(n+m)!, где n, m – неотрицательные целые числа.(Определить внутреннюю функцию, вычисляющую факториал)" . А вот в процессе разбора решения мне лишь непонятна функциональная сторона вот здесь "return !q ? 1: q*fact(q-1);}" и для чего осуществляется рекурсия

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@amora](/users/15886/amora), попробую расписать функцию `fact()` поподробнее. Кстати, раз уж в задании сказано, что `n` и `m` *целые неотрицательные числа*, то и функцию сделаем для них, а не для `float`.

Для начала. Запись:

```
 unsigned int
 fact (unsigned int q) {
   return !q ? 1 : q * fact(q - 1);
 }
```

это просто сокращенная форма вот такой:

```
 unsigned int
 fact (unsigned int q) {
   if (q == 0)   // проверка, соответствующая !q
      return 1;  // это часть перед ":" в тернарном операторе в return !q ? 1 : ...
   else
      return q * fact(q - 1); // естественно, правая, т.е. после ":" часть
 }
```

более привычной (пока для Вас) записи того же алгоритма.

Думаю, что сам алгоритм после вот такой записи n! :

```
 n! = n * (n - 1) * (n - 2) * ... * 2 * 1 * 1
```

(фактически я просто перевернул запись из комментария [@paulgri](/users/14613/paulgri)) очевиден.

Теперь посмотрим на коротком примере, что происходит при рекурсии. Время течет слева направо, а стек активаций функции растет сверху вниз. Переменные я заменяю их значениями.

```
main: func(3)                  оп-па результат 3! == 6
  func: 3 * func(2)          return 3 * 2
    func: 2 * func(1)      return 2 * 1
      func: 1 * func(0)  return 1 * 1
        func:   return 1
```

Вот так работает рекурсивный вариант функции вычисления факториала.

Понятно, что уже при небольшом значении `n` в ходе вычислений возникнет переполнение. Результат очередного умножения не поместится в 32 бита типа `unsigned int`. Несколько отсрочит столь плачевный конец переход к типу `unsigned long long` (64 разряда), возвращаемому функцией. Т.е. вот такой ее вид:

```
unsigned long long fact(unsigned int q) { return q ? q * fact( q - 1) : 1; }
```

несколько больше удовлетворит наше любопытство.

(замена !q ? на q ? само собой ничего не меняет, просто IMHO выглядит красивей).

Comment: @amora, больше по этому поводу вопросов нет?

Comment: Спасибо Вам за подробное объяснение)Пока лучшее, что я видела)

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу [@avp](/users/232/avp): метод, которым в вашем примере вычисляется `C_n^k`, ужасно неэффективен, и скорее всего приведёт к переполнению даже в тех случаях, когда результат помещается в `int`.

Гораздо лучше, быстрее, проще и эффективнее считать с использованием рекуррентной формулы:

```
C_n^k = C_n^{n-k}                   (*)
C_n^0 = 1                           (**)
C_n^k/C_n^{k-1} = { n! / (k!(n-k)!) } / { n! / ((k-1)!(n-k+1)!)} =
                = { (k-1)! / (k!) } * { (n-k+1)!/(n-k)! } =
                = (n-k+1)/k         (***)
```

То есть получается вот что:

```
if (k > n/2)
    k = n - k;  // воспользовались (*)
Cni = 1;        // инвариант цикла: Cni == C_n^i
                // воспользовались (**)
for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    Cni = Cni * (n - i + 1) / i;  // воспользовались (***)

return Cni;
```